# jqgrid - edit type select with HTML encoded data displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, html, grid, drop-down-menu, encode

I am performing an inline edit, and have the edit type of one of the columns set to be a drop down. Some of the entries in JSON for the drop down have html encoded characters – which is causing an entry of "undefined" to be displayed in the drop down.:

Definition of the column:

```
{
    "name":"id_secretary",
    "index":"id_secretary",
    "hidden":false,
    "edittype":"select",
    "editable":true,
    "formatter":"select",
    "editoptions": {
        "value":"null:;  …  87604:NKWABI NG&#039;HNGE;87613:NSOMA MIGAMBA;87629:NTUBI NSHAAHI;87608:NZEGELA MADUHU;87600:NZILA MALUGU;87606:NZILINZI AMINI;87591:PIUS NGWALALI;87586:SAGANDA JOHN;87607:SAKA NG&#039;HONGE;87618:SALU ND&#039;HWANI;87614:SEMELA MALAGU;87625:SHAURI KILULU;87621:SHILINGI KILULU;87585:SULAY SHIJA;87623:TIPA KITEJA;87598:TUMA ISEME",
        "multiple":false
}
```

Is there a way to handle HTML encoded characters in the drop down, or should the JSON data I return not contain these in the first place?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe both javascript and jqgrid have htmlDecode() functions that should be fix those entities right up for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use a jqgrid parameter for that, set:

autoencode: true

I hope that jqGrid option autoencode: true will solve your problem.